# How to delay angular child component API call?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a component that has 2 child components on it, the parent component gets a parameter from the URL does some calculation and display some data on the template.

But I also use the URL parameter to pass to the 2 child components using the @Input() on the child components.

I'm trying to find a solution for an issue that I see if the user navigates before all the data is loaded in the child components.

So when the users navigate to the parent component I get the ID its passed on the URL call an API to display some data to the user. At the same time I pass that ID to the child component that call another API and pull more data.

The problem is that on the parent component display they user can click on a link and change the ID on the URL and that would load the new data based on the URL ID and pass it again to the child component and it would cause it to pull new data set from the API. If you click to fast before all the data is back from the API call, you can notice that the first API call on the child component is still happening and the second call is initiated.

So what happens is you will see the first API data displayed and after the 2nd call is finished the data will update on the child component with the new data set.

What is the best way to prevent this from happening? Should I add a delay to the child API call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you've already got the parent updating the child with changing IDs.

If you get the child to treat its `@Input` as an `Observable`, you can then take advantage of `switchMap` to automatically cancel pending HTTP requests if the incoming ID changes before the HTTP request completes.

You could achieve this by:

1. setting up a private `Subject` instance in the child to hold the ID,
2. using `ngOnChanges` to keep that `Subject` updated with ID changes,
3. piping that `Subject` (as an `Observable`) through `switchMap` to get an HTTP request `Observable` based off the current ID, and
4. performing any work on the response in a subscription to that `Observable`.

The following (untested) code should be close to what you need:

```js
private id: Subject = new BehaviorSubject(null);
private data: Observable;
private sub: Subscription;

ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if (changes['id']) {
        this.id.next(changes['id']);
    }
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.data = this.id.asObservable().pipe(
        filter(id => id !== null),
        switchMap(id => GET_RESPONSE_OBSERVABLE_FOR(id)),
        map(response => {
            // build & return data structure suitable for template
        })
    );
    this.sub = this.data.subscribe(data => {
        // update child according to data
    });
}

ngOnDestroy() {
    this.sub.unsubscribe();
}
```

If you can subscribe to the observable in the template using the `async` pipe, then you don't even need to manually unsubscribe at `ngOnDestroy` time.

This approach removes the need for any hard-coded delay.

Comment: That is a good point, thanks for the idea on treating the @Input as an Observable I will add it here.

Comment: I've added some example code to help you get started.

Answer (score 1):

So in this scenario what you can do. Make the child input as `Observable`.
Emits the {id} to child when parent completes with the data loading.

**Parent component**

```
@Input() ID: string;
public id$: Observable<string>;

ngOnInit(){
   this.httpService.get('urltofetchdatawith{ID}')
    .subscribe(data =>{
        if(data){
           // After fetching the data in parent emit the {id} to child
           this.id$ = new Observable<string>(ob => ob.next(this.ID));
        }
    })
}
```

**Parent component template**

```
<child-component [id]="id$"> </child-component>
```

**Child component**

```
@Input() id: Observable<string>;

ngOnChanges(){
   if(id){
      this.id
        .pipe(
           map(value => value),
           switchMap(value => this.httpService('urltofetchdata{value}'))
        )
        .subscribe(data =>{
            // Child data
        })
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use switch map to achieve it. 
https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html